# Extract the xpath for every node (tag) from XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I just have the similar like the following XML file :

```
<xml>
    <Catalog>
        <Book>
            <Textbook>
                <Author ="MEMO" />
            </Textbook>
        </Book>
        <Journal>
            <Science>
                <Author ="David" />
            </Science>
        </Journal>
    </Catalog>
</xml>
```

what i would like to do that write a python code that will find and print the xpath for every nodes in my XML file , any idea or suggest i will be very thankful :), any models i can use to find the full path example the result should look like :

MEMO: Catalog/Book/Textbook/Author

Comment: that looks like an interesting problem, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with lxml:

```
import lxml.html as lh
from lxml import etree

books = """[your html above]"""

doc = lh.fromstring(books)

tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)
for e in doc.iter('author'):
    print("Memo: ",tree.getpath(e).replace('/xml/',''))
```

Output:

```
Memo:  catalog/book/textbook/author
Memo:  catalog/journal/science/author
```